# Cppcheck support in CMake

Tags: cmake, cppcheck

I am not asking about the various available third-party modules that support Cppcheck in one way or the other.

With CMake 3.10, CMake seems to have gained some official Cppcheck support. See [CMAKE_<LANG>_CPPCHECK](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/variable/CMAKE_LANG_CPPCHECK.html#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_CPPCHECK).

Unfortunately the documentation on how to use this variable is a bit sparse. Is there a good example of how Cppcheck is supposed to be used with CMake 3.10 (or later)?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

An [simple example](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.html#idm63) would be - if you have `cppcheck` in your `PATH` and you are not specifying additional parameters - the following by setting global [`CMAKE_<LANG>_CPPCHECK`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_CPPCHECK.html) variable:

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(CppCheckTest)

file(
    WRITE "main.cpp"
[=[
int main()
{
    char a[10];
    a[10] = 0;
    return 0;
}
]=] 
)

set(CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK "cppcheck")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")
```

The files to scan are added automatically to the `cppcheck` command line. So the above example gives the following output (`gcc` and `cppcheck` on Linux system):

```
# make
Scanning dependencies of target CppCheckTest
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/CppCheckTest.dir/main.cpp.o
Checking .../CppCheckTest/main.cpp...
Warning: cppcheck reported diagnostics:
[/mnt/c/temp/StackOverflow/CppCheckTest/main.cpp:4]: (error) Array 'a[10]' accessed at index 10, which is out of bounds.
[100%] Linking CXX executable CppCheckTest
[100%] Built target CppCheckTest
```

You could give `cppcheck` a try in an existing project by simply setting the `CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK` variable via the `cmake` command line:

```
# cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK:FILEPATH=cppcheck ..
```

A more "daily life" example would probably for you to include something like the following code snippet in your `CMakeList.txt`:

```perl
find_program(CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK NAMES cppcheck)
if (CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK)
    list(
        APPEND CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK 
            "--enable=warning"
            "--inconclusive"
            "--force" 
            "--inline-suppr"
            "--suppressions-list=${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CppCheckSuppressions.txt"
    )
endif()
```

**References**

- [CMake Commit: Add properties to run cppcheck along with the compiler](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/311b7b1a7095ec460fab950a6767571eb3b9652c)
- [`<LANG>_CPPCHECK` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LANG_CPPCHECK.html)

  > This property is supported only when `<LANG>` is `C` or `CXX`.
  >
  > Specify a ;-list containing a command line for the `cppcheck` static analysis tool. The Makefile Generators and the Ninja generator will run `cppcheck` along with the compiler and report any problems.
  >
  > This property is initialized by the value of the `CMAKE_<LANG>_CPPCHECK` variable if it is set when a target is created.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, unfortunately it doesn't work here (Ubuntu 17.10, cppcheck 1.80 cmake 3.9.1. There is no output from cppcheck. How to debug this?

Comment: @arved Are you sure that this also works with CMake 3.9.x? Havn't checked this. I'm using CMake 3.10.x. The commit I've linked is 5 month old, so I suspect that it only works in 3.10.x (also if I look at the [release notes](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/release/3.10.html#properties) it was added with Version 3.10).

Comment: you are right, i misread the release notes, it works with 3.10

Comment: I would like the compile to fail if there is acppcheck error or warning. I tried `--error-exitcode=1` but unfortunately it did not have any effect. ( I know I can roll my own cppcheck target of course - but would be nice if it worked with the built in support ).

Comment: The "daily life" example provided does **not** work (at least using a Ninja generator with CMake 3.12.4)! It seems that `CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK` has to be **fully** specified on the CLI. Otherwise the build system does not pick up the value of `CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK`. I had it almost working by setting the variable manually as a `CACHE` variable in my `CMakeLists.txt`, but even then *configure* has to be run **twice** in order for the generator to pick up the updated `CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK` value. Guess: Build files are written in wrong order. I'm afraid the only portable solution is a custom target.

Comment: Interestingly, when `make` is invoked with parallel jobs `-jX`, cppcheck output is garbled and ureadable.

Comment: I also try this but does not work for me with the latest cmake version. cppcheck is found on configure but when I build the proejct i did not get any cppcheck output.  Did anyone has  a link to a sample project?

Comment: I am also not getting the cppcheck output using the provided "daily life" example. mgiaco and @Florian Wolter, Did you guys got the fix to make that work? Could you also look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65525407/how-do-i-compile-and-integrate-cppcheck-with-cmake-on-vs-code?noredirect=1#comment115848861_65525407)

Comment: There's a easily overlooked point. The CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK must be defined BEFORE defining the target. Maybe this is the reason of your problem. @FlorianWolters

Answer (score 1):

Starting with [CMake 3.5, setting](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html) `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` to `ON` creates `compile_commands.json` in the build directory. Since [version 1.76](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/releases/tag/1.76) Cppcheck can open such CMake project files with `--project=`.

**Example**
Usually, you configure and build (using `make`) your project like this:

```
mkdir build
cmake <config options> ..
make
```

To run Cppcheck, you have to adjust:

```
mkdir build
cmake <config options> -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON ..
cppcheck --project=compile_commands.json --enable=all
```

**Personal opinion**
For manual uses, the feature to tell CMake to run Cppcheck (by setting `CMAKE_<LANG>_CPPCHECK`) is not useful for manual Cppcheck runs. This feature is meant to be used in a continuous testing system.

Comment: Curious that this seems to be undocumented.